# Walk along 2D numpy array as long as values remain the same

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

**Short description**
I want to walk along a numpy 2D array starting from different points in specified directions (either 1 or -1) until a column changes (see below)

**Current code**

First let's generate a dataset:

```
# Generate big random dataset
# first column is id and second one is a number
np.random.seed(123)
c1 = np.random.randint(0,100,size = 1000000)
c2 = np.random.randint(0,20,size = 1000000)
c3 = np.random.choice([1,-1],1000000 )
m = np.vstack((c1, c2, c3)).T
m = m[m[:,0].argsort()]
```

Then I wrote the following code that starts at specific rows in the matrix (`start_points`) then keeps extending in the specified direction (`direction_array`) until the metadata changes:

```
 def walk(mat, start_array):
    start_mat       = mat[start_array]
    metadata        = start_mat[:,1]
    direction_array = start_mat[:,2]
    walk_array      = start_array
    
    while True:
        walk_array = np.add(walk_array, direction_array)
        try:
            walk_mat = mat[walk_array]
            walk_metadata = walk_mat[:,1]
            if sorted(metadata) != sorted(walk_metadata):
                raise IndexError
        except IndexError:
            return  start_mat, mat[walk_array + (direction_array *-1)]
            
s = time.time()
for i in range(100000):
    start_points = np.random.randint(0,1000000,size = 3)
    res = walk(m, start_points)
```

**Question**
While the above code works fine I think there must be an easier/more elegant way to walk along a numpy 2D array from different start points until the value of another column changes? This for example requires me to slice the input array for every step in the while loop which seems quite inefficient (especially when I have to run `walk` millions of times).

Comment: Can you provide an example with a small amount of deterministic input data and expected output data?

Comment: Are you sure `direction_array` shouldn't be updated in the while loop? This code can be vectorized, but only IF `direction_array` does indeed stay constant and is not re-read from `mat` at each iteration...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to whole input array in while loop. You could just use the column that values you want to check.

I refactored a little bit your code as well so there is no `while True` statement and so there is no `if` that raises error for no particular reason.

Code:

```py
def walk(mat, start_array):
    start_mat = mat[start_array]
    metadata = sorted(start_mat[:,1])
    direction_array = start_mat[:,2]
    
    data =  mat[:,1]
    walk_array = np.add(start_array, direction_array)
    
    try:
        while metadata == sorted(data[walk_array]):
            walk_array = np.add(walk_array, direction_array)
    except IndexError:
        pass
        
    return start_mat, mat[walk_array - direction_array]
```

In this particular reason if `len(start_array)` is a big number (thousands of elements) you could use `collections.Counter` instead of sort as it will be much faster.

I was thinking of another approach that could be used and I that there could be a array with desired slices in correct direction.
But this approach seems very dirty. Anyway I will post it maybe you will find it anyhow useful

Code:

```py
def walk(mat, start_array):
    start_mat = mat[start_array]
    metadata = sorted(start_mat[:,1])
    direction_array = start_mat[:,2]

    _data = mat[:,1]
    walk_slices = zip(*[
        data[start_points[i]+direction_array[i]::direction_array[i]]
        for i in range(len(start_points))
    ])
    
    for step, walk_metadata in enumerate(walk_slices):
        if metadata != sorted(walk_metadata):
            break
    return start_mat, mat[start_array + (direction_array * step)]
```

Answer (score 0):

To perform operation starting from a **single** row, define the following class:

```
class Walker:
    def __init__(self, tbl, row):
        self.tbl = tbl
        self.row = row
        self.dir = self.tbl[self.row, 2]

    # How many rows can I move from "row" in the indicated direction
    # while metadata doesn't change
    def numEq(self):
        # Metadata from "row" in the required direction
        md = self.tbl[self.row::self.dir, 1]
        return ((md != md[0]).cumsum() == 0).sum() - 1

    # Get row "n" positions from "row" in the indicated direction
    def getRow(self, n):
        return self.tbl[self.row + n * self.dir]
```

Then, to get the result, run:

```
def walk_2(m, start_points):
    # Create walkers for each starting point
    wlk = [ Walker(m, n) for n in start_points ]
    # How many rows can I move
    dist = min([ w.numEq() for w in wlk ])
    # Return rows from changed positions
    return np.vstack([ w.getRow(dist) for w in wlk ])
```

The execution time of my code is roughly the same as yours,
but in my opinion my code is more readable and concise.